# Удаление записей из БД, отмеченных в ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Привет. 
Есть активити с листвью (элемент списка - текст и чекбокс). Данные хранятся в SQLite. Как лучше поступить, если нужно удалить чекнутые записи? Использовать в элементе списка checkedtextview? как с ним работать?
Либо в БД добавить столбец cheked, integer, и заполнять его 0 либо 1.

DB:

```
    public class DataBase {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "myDB";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DB_TABLE = "myTABLE";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_CB = "checked";
    public static final String COLUMN_TXT = "text";

    private static final String DB_CREATE =
            "create table " + DB_TABLE + "(" +
                    COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + // + COLUMN_CB + " integer, "

                    COLUMN_TXT + " text" +
                    ");";

    private final Context myContext;

    private DBHelper myDBhelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase myDB;

    public DataBase(Context myContext) {
        this.myContext = myContext;
    }

    // открыть подключение
    public void open() {
        myDBhelper = new DBHelper(myContext,DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);
        myDB=myDBhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    // закрыть подключение
    public void close() {
        if (myDBhelper!=null) myDBhelper.close();

    }

    //получить все данные из DB_TABLE
    public Cursor getAllData() {
        return myDB.query(DB_TABLE,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    // добавить запись в DB_TABLE
    public void addRec(String text) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
//        cv.put(COLUMN_CB,0);
        cv.put(COLUMN_TXT,text);
        myDB.insert(DB_TABLE,null,cv);
    }

    // удалить запись из DB_TABLE
    public void delRec (long id){
        myDB.delete(DB_TABLE,COLUMN_ID + "="+ id,null);
    }


private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DB_CREATE);
//        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
//        cv.put(COLUMN_TXT,"Проснуться");
//        sqLiteDatabase.insert(DB_TABLE,null,cv);// contentvalues ?????
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i2) {

    }
}


}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    ListView lvData;
    DataBase database;
    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        database = new DataBase(this);
        database.open();

        String[] from = new String[]{DataBase.COLUMN_TXT};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.taskname};

        lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvData);
        lvData.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);
        lvData.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    public void onAddButtonClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,InputTask.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent,1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        String descr = data.getStringExtra("task");
        database.addRec(descr);
        getLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        database.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new MyCursorLoader(this, database);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        cursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {

    }

    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {

        DataBase db;

        public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DataBase db) {
            super(context);
            this.db = db;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            Cursor cursor = db.getAllData();
            return cursor;
        }

    }
}
```

MainActivity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onAddButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/add_record">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onDeleteButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/delete_record">

    </Button>
</FrameLayout>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvData"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
```

item.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/taskname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:checked="true"
    />
```

Comment: почитайте, как правильно форматировать код наконец уже. 600 репутации, а код не отформатировал...

Comment: 600 это ник, так то))сорри

Comment: ага, точно, тогда в общем-то все ясно... В любом случае почитайте ,как пользоваться инструментами форматирований. Тем более, что есть превью результата

Comment: А по вопросу подскажите ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView` имеет метод [`getCheckedItemIds()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemIds()), который возвращает массив айдишников БД в связанных адаптером айтемах которых были чекнуты элементы. `ListView` должен реализовать режим `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE`. Далее уже по имеющимся айдишникам не составит труда удалить записи из БД.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!для этого в лист итеме должен быть Chekedtextview?

Comment: @600 Думаю любой элемент, реализующий интерфейс `Checkable`

Answer (score 0):

С одной стороны, конечно, *на вкус и цвет товарищей нет*, но таки есть универсальные рецепты. В частности, вводить в БД специальное поле только ради удаления - не есть правильно. Более того это противоречит концепции разделения данных от интерфейса.

Пользуйтесь либо `CheckedTextView`, либо заведите составной лейаут строки списка, который содержит `TextView` и `CheckBox`.

Как пользоваться виджетами - почитайте документацию - ничего сложного там нет.